# How to serialize checkbox value through searilizedarray()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is how to serialize checkbox value and textbox value together in one array through searilizedarray()...

now i am getting something like this

```
       [{"name":"text_input","value":"kalpit"},
        {"name":"wpc_chkbox[]","value":"Option one"},
        {"name":"wpc_chkbox[]","value":"Option two"},
        {"name":"wpc_chkboxasdf[]","value":"Option one"},
       {"name":"wpc_chkboxasdf[]","value":"Option two"},
       {"name":"wpc_inline_chkbox[]","value":"1"},
       {"name":"wpc_inline_chkbox[]","value":"2"},
       {"name":"wpc_inline_chkbox[]","value":"3"},
       {"name":"wpc_radios","value":"Option one"}]
```

but it should be like

```
     [{"name":"text_input","value":"kalpit"},
        {"name":"wpc_chkbox[]","value":"[Option one,Option Two]"},
        {"name":"wpc_chkboxasdf[]","value":"[Option one,Option Two]"},
       {"name":"wpc_inline_chkbox[]","value":"[1,2,3]"},
       {"name":"wpc_radios","value":"Option one"}]
```

i am using `var form = $('.wpc_contact').serializeArray();` to get form data

this is my html sample which I am generating dynamically using drag and drop future..

```
  <form method="POST" name="1" class="form-horizontal wpc_contact" novalidate="novalidate">
   <fieldset>
     <div id="legend" class="">
       <legend class="">Demo</legend> 
       <div id="alert-message" class="alert hidden" style="color: red;"></div>
     </div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Checkboxes</label>
    <div class="controls" name="wpc_chkbox" req="yes">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option one" id="wpc_chkbox_0" name="wpc_chkbox[]" req="yes">  Option one         
            <input type="checkbox" value="Option two" id="wpc_chkbox_1" name="wpc_chkbox[]" req="yes">   Option two
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls" name="wpc_inline_chkbox" req="yes">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="wpc_inline_chkbox[]" id="wpc_inline_chkbox_0" req="yes"> 1
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="wpc_inline_chkbox[]" id="wpc_inline_chkbox_1" req="yes"> 2
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="wpc_inline_chkbox[]" id="wpc_inline_chkbox_2" req="yes"> 3
    </div>      
</div>

<div class="control-group">      
    <div class="controls">                          
        <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>                     
    </div>                  
</div>
</fieldset>                 
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The form fields will be serialized into one array. Is this your full code? Because you haven't closed the form tag...

Comment: @user007 yes this is my full code.. sorry i missed that tag while coping..

Comment: updated my question please have look once

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   var cacheObject = {};//tmp cache for form elements name/values pairs
    var serArr = $('.wpc_contact').serializeArray();

    //set values of elements to cacheObject
    $.each(serArr, function (arrayIndex,obj) {
        if (cacheObject[obj.name]) {
            cacheObject[obj.name].push(obj.value);
        } else {
            cacheObject[obj.name] = [obj.value];
        }
    });

    //create new serialized array
    var newSerArr = [];
    $.each(cacheObject, function (key, value) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[key] = value;
        newSerArr.push(obj);
    });

    console.log(newSerArr);//looks like serializeArray
```

Comment: what is checkboxes here?

Comment: Although it's not bad, keep in mind that this will not result in exactly what OP wants. Single values will be encapsulated in arrays, and the whole object will not be an array.

Comment: Add another loop for looking like `serializeArray` result.

Answer (score 0):

This one makes a different array and elements of same name are grouped together.

```
var form_data = $(".wpc_contact").serializeArray();
var form_array = {}; //final array where all the values will be stored

$.each(form_data, function(i, element) {

    if(jQuery('input[name="'+element.name+'"]:checked').length>0)
        {  

          replaced = element.name.replace('[]',''); //removing [] from the input name
          form_array[replaced]={};

          jQuery('input[name="'+element.name+'"]:checked').each(function(j,ind){
              form_array[replaced][j] = jQuery(this).val();
          });

        }
        else
        {
          form_array[element.name] = element.value;
        }
});
console.log(form_array);
```

You can access as:

```
alert(form_array['wpc_chkbox'][0]); //no '[]' in the key
```