# How to combine same name with its value in array

Tags: php, arrays

hi I have array like this

```
   Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => text_input
        [value] => kalpit
    )

  [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => wpc_chkbox[]
        [value] => Option two
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => wpc_chkboxasdf[]
        [value] => Option one
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => wpc_chkboxasdf[]
        [value] => Option two
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => wpc_inline_chkbox[]
        [value] => 1
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => wpc_inline_chkbox[]
        [value] => 2
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => wpc_inline_chkbox[]
        [value] => 3
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => wpc_radios
        [value] => Option one
    )

 )
```

now my question is how to combine same name value in onc place, here in above array I have **wpc_inline_checkbox[]** is repeating 3 times so I want to make it .. I can use array_uniqe() but I want value of other duplicate index...

```
  [4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => wpc_inline_chkbox[]
        [value] => 1,2,3
    )
```

can anyone help me to solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate!!! >.< http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154419/how-to-serialize-checkbox-value-through-searilizedarray/21156473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming both name/value are strings

```
<?php 

  $objects;    // This is your array
  $sorted = array();  // This is the sorted array

  // Loop over your array
  foreach($objects as $object)
  {
    // Check if object exists in sorted array
    if( array_key_exists($object->name, $sorted) )
    {
      // Object with this name is already in sorted array simply add to it
      $obj = $sorted[$object->name];

      // Update the values
      $obj->value = $obj->value . ',' . $object->value;

    } else {

      // Object is not in the sorted array add it now
      $sorted[$object->name] = $object;
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your case is not ordinary, so you will need to do it by hand

```
$properArray = array();
foreach ($originArray as $value) {
    if ( ! isset($properArray[$value['name']])) {
        $properArray[$value['name']] = array(
            'name' = $value['name'],
            'value' = ''
        );
    }
    if (isset($properArray[$value['name']]['value'])) {
         $properArray[$value['name']]['value'] = $properArray[$value['name']]['value'] . ',' .$value['value']; //better to use array in this place
    } else {
         $properArray[$value['name']]['value'] = $value['value']
    }

}

$originArray = array_values($properArray);
```

regards,

Comment: How is it not ordinary simply sorting and merging why make it so messy.

Comment: Because you need to merge some values in array by the key which is another value - I think there is no function in PHP purposed to manage this problem, so in conclusion it's not so ordinary as you might think.

Comment: This is one of the most trivial problems, you get to solve in high school computer science classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of object. You will have to loop through and assign them. Something like

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $obj) {
  if (!isset($newArray[$obj->name])) {
    $newArray[$obj->name] = $obj;
  } else {
    $newArray[$obj->name]->value .= ",{$obj->value}";
  }
}
```

The new array should look like

```
["wpc_inline_chkbox[]"] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => wpc_inline_chkbox[]
        [value] => "1,2,3"
    )
```

But you should change [value] from string to array.

Answer (score 0):

## Use this ##

```
$arr = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'hi'
            ,'value' => 1
        )
        ,array(
            'name' => 'hi'
        ,'value' => 2
        )
        , array(
            'name' => 'hi2'
        ,'value' => 1
        )
        , array(
            'name' => 'hi4'
        ,'value' => 1
        )
        ,array(
            'name' => 'hi0'
        ,'value' => 4
        )
        , array(
            'name' => 'hi0'
        ,'value' => 3
        )
        , array(
            'name' => 'hi1'
        ,'value' => 10
        )
    );
    print_r($arr);
    $arrTracker = array();
    for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($arr) ;$i++) {
        for($j = $i+1; $j<sizeof($arr);$j++){
            if($arr[$i]['name'] == $arr[$j]['name']){
                $arr[$i]['value'] .= ','.$arr[$j]['value'];
                $arrTracker[$j] = $j;
            }
        }
    }
    // if you want to unset duplicate name and corresponding value, use below forloop, otherwise it's unnecessary
    foreach($arrTracker as $tracker){
        unset($arr[$tracker]);
    }
    $arr = array_values($arr);
    print_r($arr);
```